# How to triger a function after draw delete?

Tags: leaflet-draw

I'm using Leaflet draw and I want that after the user remove the path he created it will trigger a function.
After the user finished drawing a path I also do something:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (event) {});
```

Any idea?

Also, I want to let the user upload a gpx file, how can I convert it to GeoJSON in order to display and store it in my db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS shown in the [leaflet.js docs](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event-draw:deleted)

I just need to change the draw:created to draw:deketed.